# Iptables port hijacking

Tags: iptables, iptables-redirect

I have an application listening on port 2000. I want to proxy all traffic to this port (originating locally) to a different port, say 4000.

Right now i am doing something like this.

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -p tcp --dport 2000 -d 127.0.0.1 -j DNAT --to-destination 127.0.0.1:4000
```

This works as long as there is nothing listening on 2000. if I telnet to 2000, traffic is routed to 4000 as expected. But if there is something listening on 2000, the traffic is not hijacked/proxied. Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You likely have to add the rule to the prerouting chain, not the output

Comment: I have tried that to no effect. As far as I know the loopback interface is not affected by PREROUTING.